# How to make handlebars keep indentation when replacing a multi-line value?

Tags: html, handlebars.js

Consider this handlebars template:

```
<div>
    {{content}}
</div>
```

And the following data:

```
{
    content: 'foo\r\nbar'
}
```

And the desired result (what I need):

```
<div>
    foo
    bar
</div>
```

But when compiling the handlebars template with the data I get this:

```
<div>
    foo
bar
</div>
```

So, how to make handlebars keep indentation when replacing a multi-line value? 
Of course, changing the data is not an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the `compile` reference](http://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/compilation.html#handlebars-compile-template-options):

> `preventIndent`: By default an indented partial-call causes the output of the whole partial being indented by the same amount. This can lead to unexpected behavior when the partial writes pre-tags. Setting this option to `true` will disable the auto-indent feature.

So, it follows that if you're able to set up your template so that `content` is rendered by a partial, e.g.:

```
<div>
    {{> ContentPartial}}
</div>
```

Then before it's rendered, [register the `ContentPartial` partial](http://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partials):

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('ContentPartial', '{{content}}')
```

then it will preserve indentation. (I actually discovered this feature when the auto-indentation screwed up formatting in my `<textarea>` and I had to disable it).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Handlebars didn't know anything about the place where data will be embedded. You have line break in data and you get line break in result, there is no and nowhere to get  a tab (4 spaces) after `foo`, have just one line break.

One of the ways to deal with your problem is to use such helper, that knows about the indentation and process passed argument proper way.

See quick example.

Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('indent', function (data, indent) {
  var out = data.replace(/\n/g, '\n' + indent);
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(out);
});
```

used as:

```
{{indent foo '   '}}
```

will produce you multiline output with specified indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @tobias-j answer, the partial can be written inline with no need to register it on the code.

So, your template can be written as:

```
{{#*inline "inlineContent"}}
{{content}}
{{/inline}}
<div>
    {{> inlineContent}}
</div>
```

You can see it working on the [playground](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22%7B%7B%23*inline%20%5C%22inlineContent%5C%22%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7Bcontent%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B%2Finline%7D%7D%5Cn%3Cdiv%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%3E%20inlineContent%7D%7D%5Cn%3C%2Fdiv%3E%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20content%3A%20%27foo%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cnbar%27%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22%3Cdiv%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20foo%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20bar%5Cn%3C%2Fdiv%3E%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22%5Cn%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.7.7%22%7D).